# Python read csv read row by row and loop fuction

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, google-maps-api-3, google-search

I want to automate a task in Python with the Google API Search Place. Right now, my code with Google Maps API is returning places 'hospital' for one set of geographic coordinates.

But, I have a CSV file which contains many geographic coordinates.

```
1: Hanoi,10.762622,106.660172  
2: Ho Chi Minh,12.762622,108.660175  
3: Ho Chi Minh,11.8542,108.660175 
4: ...
5: ...
```

As you can see in my code, this is not efficient because I need to change the geographic coordinates manually.

For each row (geographic coordinates) in my CSV file, I want my code to read the geographic coordinates 1: Hanoi and give me results 'hospitals' for this geographic coordinates. After read row 2: Ho Chi Minh and same for all the other rows.

How I can achieve that or any good examples of making tasks like this more efficient?

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import json

googleGeocodeUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query='
keyword = "hospital"
geolocation = "&location=-12.135,-77.023&radius=5000"
APIKEY = '&key='+'apikey'

url = googleGeocodeUrl + keyword + geolocation + APIKEY
print(url)

url = googleGeocodeUrl + keyword + geolocation + APIKEY
json_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
search = json_response.read().decode('utf-8')
searchjson = json.loads(search)

export = open('hopital.csv','w')
for place in searchjson['results']:
    print(place['name'])
    print(place['geometry']['location'])
export.write(place['name']+','+str(place['geometry']['location']['lng'])\
 +','+str(place['geometry']['location']['lat'])+'\n')
export.close()
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to give some examples?

Comment: Please ensure the API key you have entered is not your real API key.

Comment: @MartinEvans please see examples

Comment: I assume your CSV is actually of the form  `Hanoi,10.762622,106.660172` without line numbers

Comment: @MartinEvans yes, it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of Python's `csv` library to help with reading and writing the CSV files. Also it is better to use a format string to aid with inserting your variables into you URL:

```
import csv
import urllib
import urllib.request
import json

googleGeocodeUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query={}&location={},{}&radius=5000&key={}'
keyword = "hospital"
key = '123'

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('hospital.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Search place', 'Name', 'Lat', 'Long'])

    for search_place, lat, long in csv_input:
        url = googleGeocodeUrl.format(urllib.parse.quote(search_place), lat, long, key)
        json_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        search = json_response.read().decode('utf-8')
        searchjson = json.loads(search)

        for place in searchjson['results']:
            row = [place['name'], place['geometry']['location']['lng'], place['geometry']['location']['lat']]
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

The format string works using quite a powerful mini language, but at its simplest, you just need to add `{}` as a placeholder for what you want to replace. For each `{}` that is used, format replaces it with the matching argument when it is called, e.g.

```
'test{}'.format(123)
'lat is {}, long is {}'.format(123, 456)
```

Comment: I don't get it how you specify to read the latitude and longitude coordinates... My CSV should have headings which specify location, latitude, longitude?

Comment: You have 3 columns. The `csv.reader()` will read one row and split it automatically into a list of 3 values. The `for` statement provides one argument for each value. Try adding `print(search_place, lat, long)` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to test it as I don't have a suitable key. I had assumed your code was working for the manual version.

Comment: I would suggest you add more print statement to see what is being returned, e.g. `print(search)`

Comment: The API key is working in my original code but it's ''invalid key" when I use it in your code.    
                                   C:\Users\renau\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Bad Request  {
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: I suggest you `print(url)` and spot any differences with your manual version. I have also removed the trailing `;` character. Also as your places have spaces in them, they might need to be converted to `%20`. I have added support for that.

Comment: Your a legend! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'm using the code in Vietnam and it seems the Vietnamese caracthers create this error : UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ebf' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Try adding `encoding='utf-8'` as a parameter to the open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv` library included in Python's standard library for this purpose.

Specifically, [csv.DictReader()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [csv.writer()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

**`csv.DictReader()` example:**

```
import csv

with open('places.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=["place", "longitude", "latitude"])
    places = [row for row in reader]

for row in places:
    # your code here
```

**`csv.writer()` example:**

```
import csv

with open('hopital.csv','w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for place in searchjson['results']:
        writer.writerow([place['name'],
            str(place['geometry']['location']['lng']),
            str(place['geometry']['location']['lat'])])
```

---

Additionally, you could also make use of [urllib.parse.urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) for auto generating an argument string from a dict of params and values.